# How to a conversion Eigen::TensorMap to float*?

Tags: c++11, tensorflow

I am implementing a tensorflow::op (https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/how_tos/adding_an_op/#verify_it_works).

I want to call a function forward(), which takes float pointer as arguments. On the first argument, I am not  able to convert the tensor to a float pointer.

```
REGISTER_OP("ForwardMatching")
.Input("input0: float32")
.Input("input1: float32")
.Input("disparities: float32")
.Input("output: float32")
.Input("in: int32")
.Input("ic: int32")
.Input("ih: int32")
.Input("iw: int32")
.Input("lendisps: int32")
.Input("memorylayout: int32")
.Input("rectcorr: int32")
.Output("zeroed: int32")
.SetShapeFn([](::tensorflow::shape_inference::InferenceContext* c) {
    c->set_output(0, c->input(0));
    return Status::OK();
});
class ForwardMatchingOp : public OpKernel {
public:
    std::vector<cudnnTensorDescriptor_t> a;
    StereoCorrelation* sc = new StereoCorrelation(a);
    explicit ForwardMatchingOp(OpKernelConstruction* context) : OpKernel(context) {}
        void Compute(OpKernelContext* context) override {
            // Grab the input tensor
            const Tensor& input0_tensor = context->input(0);
            iu::TensorGpu_32f::MemoryLayout ml;
            float *i0, *i1, *disp;
            int in, ic, ih, iw, lendisps, rectcor;
            float *output;
            sc->forward(input0,i1,disp, output, in, ic, ih, iw, lendisps, ml, rectcor);
    } 
};
```

the error message:

```
note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<const float, 1, 1, long int>, 16, Eigen::MakePointer>’ to ‘float*’
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion is

```
Tensor A;
float *a_data = A.flat<float>().data();
size_t a_len = A.NumElements()
```

Here [`flat()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h#L272-L309) returns an Eigen::Tensor:

```
/// \brief Return the tensor data as an `Eigen::Tensor` of the data type and a
/// specified shape.
template <typename T>
typename TTypes<T>::Flat flat() {
  return shaped<T, 1>({NumElements()});
}
```

and [`data()`](https://github.com/eigenteam/eigen-git-mirror/blob/master/Eigen/src/Core/ArrayWrapper.h#L73-L75) is Eigen-specific.
The [`NumElements()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h#L137) is

```
/// Convenience accessor for the tensor shape.
int64 NumElements() const { return shape().num_elements(); }
```

Comment: This `const` is a requirement from your custom code not from the TensorFlow API.

Comment: how did you help yourself?  this is more interesting. just getting the solution.

Comment: Mostly reading through the TensorFlow header files in `${HOME}/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/include` and some experience with [Eigen](https://github.com/PatWie/CppNumericalSolvers) and [TF](https://github.com/PatWie/tensorflow_inference). A good IDE should help as well.

Comment: Doesn't work. What the OP get is not a tensor, but a TensorMap object, I tried your solution. Didn't work. I met the same error, don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @StayFoolish Of course this works, see my implementation here
https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/blob/5f618fdb92d9737da059de2a33fa606e97505398/tensorflow_addons/custom_ops/layers/cc/kernels/correlation_cost_op_gpu.cu.cc#L347